# Select specific columns with cast using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, select, sqlalchemy, casting

I'm using SQLAlchemy (Version: 1.4.44) and I'm having some unexpected results when trying to select columns and using cast on those columns.

First, most of the examples and even current documentation suggests column selection should work by passing an array to the select function like this:

```
s = select([table.c.col1])
```

However, I get the following error if I try this:

```
s = my_table.select([my_table.columns.user_id])

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected, got [Column('user_id', String(), table=<my_table>)].
```

Some examples suggest just placing the field directly in the select query.

```
s = select(table.c.col1)
```

But this seems to do nothing more than create an idle where-clause out of the field.

I eventually was able to achieve column selection with this approach:

```
s = my_table.select().with_only_columns(my_table.columns.created_at)
```

But I am not able to use cast for some reason with this approach.

```
s = my_table.select().with_only_columns(cast(my_table.columns.created_at, Date))

ValueError: Couldn't parse date string '2022' - value is not a string.
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `table.select()` is common usage.  SQLAlchemy is in a big transition right now on its way to 2.0.  In 1.4 (and in 2) the following syntax should work, use whatever session handling you already have working I just mean the `select(...)`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, cast
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INTEGER

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(
        Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True
    )
    name = Column(Text)

with Session(engine) as session:
    u1 = User(name="1")
    session.add(u1)
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    my_table = User.__table__
    # Cast user name into integer.
    print (session.execute(select(cast(my_table.c.name, INTEGER))).all())
```

Comment: Indeed. `my_table.select(…)` results in "RemovedIn20Warning: The legacy calling style of select() is deprecated and will be removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0.  Please use the new calling style described at select(). (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)"